# Ubuntu 23.10 - No sound Asus Zenbook UM3402YAR_UM3402Y

Tags: sound, asus, speakers

I have installed Ubuntu 23.10 on my laptop and get no sound from the speakers. I've searched the internet (here as well) and see that this seems to be the problem with Asus laptops. However, I've not found anyone to have the problem on this particular model.

The speakers work fine on Windows (dual boot).

Appreciate any help...as I would really like to use linux and not windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this solved by:

1. Installing fresh edition of Nobara 39;
2. following the steps written by farfaaa here https://github.com/farfaaa/asus_zenbook_UM3402YA#readme
   Steps 1 and 2 gave me sound, but the volume was lower than normal. In order to get the sound on par with windows I followed the steps written by ransor0t here https://gist.github.com/masselstine/8fe9634b4c31cef07b8dfab089e4eb38 (grabbing the soundcard files from the windows partition; renaming them into linux naming convention by usinng the provided rename script and copying the newly renamed files into /lib/firmware/cirrus.

Finally, many thanks  to ASUS for making me learn all about patching the linux kernel in order to have sound on my favorite OS in the year 2024:(

Answer (score 0):

It seems its related to Realtek drivers on the Linux kernels. After a long research, I have found out [this one](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206289). See the [13rd comment](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206289#c13), the second one works perfectly on my Asus Vivobook Pro 15 K6500ZH. Well, as this is an temporary solution, it resets every reboot. Expect a kernel patch soon I guess.

Answer (score 0):

if you do a `sudo dmesg | grep CSC` you will be able to confirm is related to the CSC3551 ADC if you see something like this:

```
   11.503864] Serial bus multi instantiate pseudo device driver CSC3551:00: Instantiated 2 SPI devices.
[   12.242906] cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
[   12.242933] cs35l41-hda spi0-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
```

The CSC3551 is involved in initialising and controlling the two CS35l41 amplifiers on many of the Asus laptops. Probably also yours as the advert for it speaks about a "smart amplifier" which fits the bill for the CS35l41.

The problem arises because Asus couldn't be bothered to properly populate the ACPI tables so the CSC3551 has no idea how to talk to the amps.

These drive the speakers hence the reason they don't work but sound works via headphone jack and HDMI.

You're best bet at fixing this issue (besides waiting for the kernel devs to get round to it), is to follow the advice [here](https://asus-linux.org/wiki/cirrus-amps/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/lamperez/862763881c0e1c812392b5574727f6ff?permalink_comment_id=4526397) and see if you can get it to work yourself.

Also if we all whinge to Asus to update the bios on our machines I think that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue a few weeks ago. Here is my post: [No sound Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / Windows 11 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506682/no-sound-ubuntu-22-04-lts-windows-11-dual-boot)

What worked for me was updating the kernel to a version at least higher than 6.7.6